# XSL applying tags incorrectly

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a class project I'm working on but I've hit a point where I'm stuck and don't know what to do. My XSL (style6.xsl) works to an extent but it creates text instead of wrapping a chunk of my xml (Project6style.xml) so I have 2 sets of text but one isn't wrapped in any tags. I've spent all day trying to figure out why it's been doing this but I can't figure it out. I was hoping someone would be able to take a look at it.

If anyone could help it would be appreciated!

https://www.mediafire.com/?4b74nb1iltdqsqx

File Reference:

style6.xsl (what I need to edit so it looks a certain way)

Project6style.xml (what was given to me in the class project folder)

Tutorial.06 Project.doc (The assignment word document)

XSL Current Output.html (what my current xsl file is giving me)

XSL Output - WHAT IT SHOULD BE.html (What I'm assuming my professor wants it to look like)

Code for those who don't want to download:

XSL:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0"/>

            <xsl:template match="project">
            <html>
                <body>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <h1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="student"/>
                </h1>
                <h2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
                </h2>
                </body>
            </html>
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="objective">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                <h4>
                    <xsl:value-of select=".//name"/>
                </h4>
                <div>
                    <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                </div>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!-- XML Project 6 -->
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style6.xsl" ?>
    <project>
    <student>Student</student>
    <date>Date</date>
    <objective>
        <name>Working with XSL</name>
        <description>XSL is composed of three parts: XSL-FO 
        (Extensible Style sheet Language - Formatting Objects),
         XSLT (Extensible Style sheet Language Transformations),
         and XPath.  XSL-FO is used to implement page layout and design.
         XSLT is used to transform XML content into another presentation format.
         XPath is used to locate information from an XML document
         and perform operations and calculations upon that content.
        </description>
    </objective>

    <objective>
        <name>Introducing XSLT style sheets and processors</name>
        <description>An XSLT style sheet contains instructions for transforming
         the contents of an XML document into another format. An XSLT style
         sheet document is itself an XML document, but has an extension .xsl.
         An XSLT style sheet converts a source document of XML content into
         a result document containing the markup codes and other instructions
         for formatting.
        </description>  
    </objective>

    <objective>
        <name>Creating an XSLT style sheet</name>
        <description>To attach an XML file to the style sheet,
         insert the processing instruction following the first line
         in the document. An XSLT style sheet has the general structure
         of all XML documents.
        </description>  
    </objective>
    </project>
```

HTML result (What my HTML file displays with these 2 files in their current state):

```
    Student
    Date

        Working with XSL
        XSL is composed of three parts: XSL-FO 
        (Extensible Style sheet Language - Formatting Objects),
         XSLT (Extensible Style sheet Language Transformations),
         and XPath.  XSL-FO is used to implement page layout and design.
         XSLT is used to transform XML content into another presentation format.
         XPath is used to locate information from an XML document
         and perform operations and calculations upon that content.

    <h4>Working with XSL</h4><div>XSL is composed of three parts: XSL-FO 
        (Extensible Style sheet Language - Formatting Objects),
         XSLT (Extensible Style sheet Language Transformations),
         and XPath.  XSL-FO is used to implement page layout and design.
         XSLT is used to transform XML content into another presentation format.
         XPath is used to locate information from an XML document
         and perform operations and calculations upon that content.
        </div>


        Introducing XSLT style sheets and processors
        An XSLT style sheet contains instructions for transforming
         the contents of an XML document into another format. An XSLT style
         sheet document is itself an XML document, but has an extension .xsl.
         An XSLT style sheet converts a source document of XML content into
         a result document containing the markup codes and other instructions
         for formatting.

    <h4>Introducing XSLT style sheets and processors</h4><div>An XSLT style sheet contains instructions for transforming
         the contents of an XML document into another format. An XSLT style
         sheet document is itself an XML document, but has an extension .xsl.
         An XSLT style sheet converts a source document of XML content into
         a result document containing the markup codes and other instructions
         for formatting.
        </div>


        Creating an XSLT style sheet
        To attach an XML file to the style sheet,
         insert the processing instruction following the first line
         in the document. An XSLT style sheet has the general structure
         of all XML documents.

    <h4>Creating an XSLT style sheet</h4><div>To attach an XML file to the style sheet,
         insert the processing instruction following the first line
         in the document. An XSLT style sheet has the general structure
         of all XML documents.
        </div>
    <h1>Student</h1><h2>Date</h2>
```

Comment: If you want the output `<Student>student</Student>`, then you need to put `<Student>` instead of `<h2>`, for example. More often than not (99%+ of the time, it's not the parser that's incorrect :-)).

Comment: @splrs Thanks for the quick response!

I have a question though, if I switched it to <student>xls:apply...<student> how would it know to tag it as <h1>?

Comment: @splrs sorry, hit enter thinking it would return not sumbit the comment lol, how would it know to tag it correctly? Mind giving me a small snippet of what it should be so I can be on the right track? Thanks

Comment: I'm rusty (possibly massively outdated on this) but I think that your parser should just leave any tags without the `xsi` namespace exactly where they are.
So assuming your current node is called "blah" and it has the text "123" inside it, then
 `<Blah><xsi:value-of select="blah"/></Blah>` would give you `<Blah>123</Blah>.

However, as I said I'm rusty, so I defer to better judgement! If someone with a higher rep offers a solution, trust them first!

Comment: I tried putting <student> in between the <h1> tags like so   <h1>
   <student><xsl:value-of select="student"/></student>
  </h1> but it didn't work, it still creates new text and is still at the bottom rather than the top where the student xml element is. Any idea? @splrs

Comment: @DrMoney: The `apply-templates` element selects all the children nodes by default, including text nodes.  That's why you have duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible stylesheet, merely sticking to the structure of the input XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" />

 <xsl:template match="objective">
  <h4><xsl:value-of select="name" /></h4>
  <div><xsl:value-of select="description" /></div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="project">
  <h1><xsl:value-of select="student" /></h1>
  <h2><xsl:value-of select="date" /></h2>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="objective" />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
  <body>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="project" />
  </body>
 </html>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**note**: I like to be specific about the target(s) of my `apply-templates` elements (hence the `select="..."` attribute), while some people prefer implicit selection;  the choice is entirely up to you.